# Uninitialized string offset: -1 when referencing single string character with curly braces

Tags: php, string, offset

I have this code:

```
$len = strlen($string);

if ($string{$len-1} == '-') {
    // Do stuff...
}
```

However I get the following NOTICE error:

```
Uninitialized string offset: -1
```

When I `var_dump($len-1)` the value I get:

```
int 3
```

When I `var_dump($string)` I get:

```
string 'bobo' (length=4)
```

So could anyone tell me why this is causing a NOTICE error?

Comment: [**Can't reproduce your error**](https://eval.in/420936) What is the output of: `var_dump($string);` ?

Comment: It seems `$string` is empty, so just update condition `if ($len > 1 && $string{$len-1} == '-')`

Comment: Ok, I found the issue. It seems the function that code is in was being called twice during the request and whilst the first time the string was set to "bobo" as stated above, the second time it was empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent notice add additional condition to `if` statement:

```
$len = strlen($string);

if ($len > 0 && $string{$len-1} == '-')
    // Do stuff...
}
```

or use `substr` function:

```
if (substr($string, -1) == '-') {
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Comment: It's not a typo, that is valid PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @Rizier123 Actually you can get a single characters in a string using square brackets

Comment: @ValeryViktorovsky Yes, but curly brackets are valid as well. I prefer them as then you don't get confusion if you are referencing an array or not.

Comment: Check my comments under the question. I will accept your answer for helping me track this down and providing a solution. :)

Comment: What if the string is just one byte?

Answer (score 0):

```
$len = strlen($string);
if(isset($string{$len-1})){
if ($string{$len-1} == '-') {
// Do stuff...
}
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.